# Finding basis for kernel and range

Tags: linear-algebra

Define a linear transformation $T : P_3\to\mathbb{R}^4$ by
$T(p(t)) =(p(0), p(0), p(0), p(0))$

I need to find a basis for the kernel of $T$ and the range of $T$.

Can someone verify if the answers are $\{t, t^2, t^3, t^4\}$ and $(1, 1, 1, 1)$, respectively?

Comment: what is P3? ${}{}$

Comment: This is ambiguous and you haven't shown your work.

Comment: Basis for kernel should be $ \{t, t^2, t^3\} $.

Answer (score 2):

Provided by $P_3$ you mean the space of polynomials of degree $\leq 3$, then as science pointed out in the comments it should be $\{t,t^2,t^3\}$. The polynomials such that $p(0)=0$ are exactly those with constant term zero.

And for the range you are right: $T(p(t))=p(0)(1,1,1,1)\in \langle (1,1,1,1)\rangle$ (and $T$ is obviously non-zero).